# not able to fetch links from pagination using watin dll

Tags: c#, .net, pagination, web-crawler, watin

Hi i am collecting urls using watin framework. i want to traverse all the pages and collect the link and save it in one text file.I dont know how to add the pagination function.here is my code.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WatiN.Core;
namespace magicbricks
{
class Class1
{
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
IE ie = new IE();

ie.GoTo("http://www.99acres.com/property-in-chennai-ffid?search_type=QS&search_location=HP&lstAcn=HP_R&src=CLUSTER&isvoicesearch=N&keyword_suggest=chennai%20%28all%29%3B&fullSelectedSuggestions=chennai%20%28all%29&strEntityMap=W3sidHlwZSI6ImNpdHkifSx7IjEiOlsiY2hlbm5haSAoYWxsKSIsIkNJVFlfMzIsIFBSRUZFUkVOQ0VfUywgUkVTQ09NX1IiXX1d&texttypedtillsuggestion=chennai&refine_results=Y&Refine_Localities=Refine%20Localities&action=%2Fdo%2Fquicksearch%2Fsearch&suggestion=CITY_32%2C%20PREFERENCE_S%2C%20RESCOM_R");

foreach (var currLink in ie.Links)
{
if (currLink.Url.Contains("b"))
{
Console.WriteLine(currLink.Url);
}
}

Console.ReadLine();

}

}
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working solution for that. I changed a bit your code.

```
using System;
using WatiN.Core;

namespace magicbricks
{
static class Class1
{
    private static WatiN.Core.Link _nextPageElement;
    private static string _firstPartOfAddress = "";
    private static string _lastPartOfAddress = "";
    private static int _maxPageCounter = 0;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IE ie = SetUpBrowser();
        EnterFirstWebpage(ie);
        ie.WaitForComplete();
        LookFoAllLinks(ie);
        for (int i = 2; i < _maxPageCounter; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------Next Page {0}---------------------------", i);
            Console.WriteLine(AssembleNextPageWebAddress(i));
            EnterNextWebpageUrl(ie,AssembleNextPageWebAddress(i));
            LookFoAllLinks(ie);                               
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IE SetUpBrowser()
    {
        IE ie = new IE();
        return ie;
    }

    private static void EnterFirstWebpage(IE ie)
    {
        ie.GoTo("http://www.99acres.com/property-in-chennai-ffid?search_type=QS&search_location=HP&lstAcn=HP_R&src=CLUSTER&isvoicesearch=N&keyword_suggest=chennai%20%28all%29%3B&fullSelectedSuggestions=chennai%20%28all%29&strEntityMap=W3sidHlwZSI6ImNpdHkifSx7IjEiOlsiY2hlbm5haSAoYWxsKSIsIkNJVFlfMzIsIFBSRUZFUkVOQ0VfUywgUkVTQ09NX1IiXX1d&texttypedtillsuggestion=chennai&refine_results=Y&Refine_Localities=Refine%20Localities&action=%2Fdo%2Fquicksearch%2Fsearch&suggestion=CITY_32%2C%20PREFERENCE_S%2C%20RESCOM_R");
    }

    private static void EnterNextWebpageUrl(IE ie,string url)
    {
        ie.GoTo(url);
        ie.WaitForComplete();
    }

    private static void LookFoAllLinks(IE ie)
    {
        int currentpageCounter = 0;
        var tmpUrl = string.Empty;
        const string nextPageUrl = "http://www.99acres.com/property-in-chennai-ffid-page-";
        foreach (var currLink in ie.Links)
        {
            if (currLink.Url.Contains("b"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(currLink.Url);
                try
                {                        
                    if (currLink.Name.Contains("nextbutton"))
                    {                            
                        _nextPageElement = currLink;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                                          
                }
                try
                {
                    if (currLink.GetAttributeValue("name").Contains("page"))
                    {
                        _firstPartOfAddress = currLink.Url.Substring(0, nextPageUrl.Length);
                        tmpUrl = currLink.Url.Remove(0,nextPageUrl.Length);
                        _lastPartOfAddress = tmpUrl.Substring(tmpUrl.IndexOf("?"));
                        tmpUrl = tmpUrl.Substring(0,tmpUrl.IndexOf("?"));
                        int.TryParse(tmpUrl, out currentpageCounter);
                        if (currentpageCounter > _maxPageCounter)
                        {
                            _maxPageCounter = currentpageCounter;
                            currentpageCounter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {                          
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static string AssembleNextPageWebAddress(int pageNumber)
    {
        return _firstPartOfAddress + pageNumber + _lastPartOfAddress;
    }
}
}
```

Some explanation :

variable _maxPageCounter contains max numbers of pages to lookfor links.
We are getting this here :

```
if (currLink.GetAttributeValue("name").Contains("page"))
                    {
                        _firstPartOfAddress = currLink.Url.Substring(0, nextPageUrl.Length);
                        tmpUrl = currLink.Url.Remove(0,nextPageUrl.Length);
                        _lastPartOfAddress = tmpUrl.Substring(tmpUrl.IndexOf("?"));
                        tmpUrl = tmpUrl.Substring(0,tmpUrl.IndexOf("?"));
                        int.TryParse(tmpUrl, out currentpageCounter);
                        if (currentpageCounter > _maxPageCounter)
                        {
                            _maxPageCounter = currentpageCounter;
                            currentpageCounter = 0;
                        }
                    }
```

Later we are just looping through pages, by create next address.

```
private static string AssembleNextPageWebAddress(int pageNumber)
    {
        return _firstPartOfAddress + pageNumber + _lastPartOfAddress;
    }
```

We could use here as well next button, and click it in loop.
I hope it was helpful.